# The maximum value of a trigonometric expression (without derivative)

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

For how trivial it may appear, here I am with this question: find the value of $x$ for which this expression has its maximum.

$$f(x) = 1 + 4\sin^2(x) + 4\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Without making use of derivatives, and only basing on trigonometric expressions / formulas.

What I have tried is to manipulate a bit the expression, but I couldn't be able to reach any interesting expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basics:
$$
\begin{align}
%
 \sin^{2} x &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - \cos 2 x \right) \\[3pt]
%
 \cos x \sin x &= \frac{1}{2} \sin 2x
%
\end{align}
$$

---

The target function becomes
$$
  f(x)
  = 1 + 4 \sin^{2} x + 4 \sin x \cos x
  = 3 + 2 \left( \sin 2 x - \cos 2 x \right)
\tag{1}
$$

When does $\sin \theta - \cos \theta$ achieve maximal value? When
$$
 \theta = \frac{3}{4}\pi + 2\pi k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

[image: theta]

Therefore, the function (1) achieves maximum value at
$$
 \boxed{x = \frac{3}{8}\pi + \pi k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}}
$$

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{3 \pi}{8}$? Since you have to divide by two...

Comment: @Henry Turing" You are entirely correct. Error in typing in notes. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @HenryTuring I didnt know you were allowed use graphing devices : - )

Comment: @Just_to_Answer: Hopefully, these are the images from @ Henry Turing's mind's eye.

Comment: @dantopa: No problem : ) I am just joking!!

Answer (score 2):

Using

$2 \, \sin^2 x = 1-\cos(2x)$,

$\sin(2x)=2\,\sin x \, \cos x$,

and $\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta) = \sqrt 2 \, \sin (\theta - \pi/4)$,

we get:

\begin{align}
f(x) 
& = 1 + 4\sin^2(x) + 4\sin(x)\cos(x) \\ 
& = 1 + 2 - 2\cos(2x) + 2\sin(2x) \\
& = 3 + 2(\sin(2x)-\cos(2x)) \\
& = 3 + 2 \,\sqrt 2 \, \sin (2x-\pi/4) 
\end{align}

So the max of $f(x)$ should be $3+2\sqrt 2$.